# CheckBox's isChecked not working when I set initially in java or Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-checkbox

If I set checkbox state in xml initially, It's working fine but When I set in java or Kotlin dynamically It's not working as I expected.

Like an exmaple when I am setting `isChecked = true` It supposed to show check box filled with accent color but It's only showing checking border color with accent only but did not filled the color inside.

[image]

See when I set the isChecked It's showing accent color in border only.

If I set checkbox state `checked = true` and set `isChecked = false` in java It looks like this then

[image]

Xml Code of CheckBox

```
<CheckBox
   android:checked="false"
   android:id="@+id/check_box"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_padding_8dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/check_box_title"/>
```

Kotlin Code

```
check_box.isChecked = false // Setting Uncheck
check_box.isChecked = true // Setting Checked
```

Comment: show some code samples, what have you tried?

Comment: ```check_box.isChecked = false```
This is a compile time error. It is not possible. Use `setChecked(true)` method.

Comment: @pa1pal I think you never worked with kotlin, calling checkbox.setChecked(true) and checkbox.isChecked = true is same in kotlin.

Comment: Are you trying to do this w/ a child Fragment inside a ViewPager?  I know that scenario can cause problems especially if the parent is a Fragment regardless if its v4 or not.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same with you. I've only tested this in an emulator and one real device, but I found 2 ways to do make it ticked without setting it in xml (for example, you need to fetch something from back-end first to determine whether it has to be ticked from the start or not):

1) Delay command using Handler

```
Handler().postDelayed({ checkBox?.isChecked = true }, 300)
```

2) Use `toggle()` after setting `isChecked`

```
checkBox?.isChecked = true 
checkBox?.toggle()
```

It's as if toggle triggers the UI changes. Problem is, from code above, you'll have your check box ticked, but its `isChecked` value will be `false`.

Since I have to set `enabled` too and somehow it messed up when using `toggle()`, I settled with the first way. I really hope someone find a more elegant way to solve this...

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState` to solve this problem.

The reason is when you call `setChecked(true)` it does the following tasks:

1. Change the border color.
2. Animation of setting the check inside the checkBox.

For some reason when the checkbox is hidden, it only does the first task and the second task is skipped. That's why this problem was occurring in my case. Calling `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState` solves this issue by doing both tasks at the same time without playing animation.

Comment: hi, Why `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState` solve the issue :) If you have any specific reason please write in your answer

Comment: The reason is when you call `setChecked(true)` it does following tasks
1. Change the border color.
2. Animation of setting the check inside the checkBox.
For some reason when the checkbox is hidden, it only does the first task and the second task is skipped.
That's why this problem was ocurring in my case.
Calling `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState ` solves this issue by doing both tasks at the same time without playing animation.
Hope it helps :)